# gulp-html-minify .pipe destination to original folder structure

Tags: gulp

Hello people of the North, I am trying to minify my HTML using gulp because https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights is telling me my site is too slow.

My original html files are in the structure of

```
/app/blog/page1.html
/app/contact/contactus.html
/app/xxx/xxx.html
```

With my current code the gulp output puts all of the html files into the _build folder, but this wont work for me since, on page load it will look for the html in the respective folder. Should I / can I put the minified html in its original folder so it is referenced automatically as normal?

```
 gulp.task('minify-html', function () {
            return gulp.src(configHTML.src)
                .pipe(angularify())
                .pipe(minifyHTML())
                .pipe(gulp.dest('_build/'));
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, you should try changing your code for:

```
gulp.src(configHTML.src, { base: "." })        
    .pipe(htmlmin({ collapseWhitespace: true, minifyCSS: true, minifyJS: true }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("."))
```

this will minify those files itself