# How to minify html files in folders and subfolders using gulp?

Tags: html, gulp, minify

My html files are located in folders and subfolders and sub-sub-folders.
I want to use Gulp to minify the html files and save the results in a folder structor similar to the folder structure of original html files.

I found [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32079348/gulp-html-minify-pipe-destination-to-original-folder-structure) in stack overflow, but it gives me error. Here is the error message:

```
ReferenceError: configHTML is not defined
```

I also asked chatGPT and it gave me this answer, but it is not doing anything when I run. Here is the answer:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const htmlmin = require('gulp-htmlmin');
const rename = require('gulp-rename');
const recursiveFolder = require('gulp-recursive-folder');
const ignore = require('gulp-ignore');

function minifyHTML() {
  return gulp.src(['src/**/*.html', 'src/*/**/*.html', 'src/*/*/**/*.html']) // Path to your HTML files
    .pipe(ignore.exclude('*.min.html')) // Exclude already minified files
    .pipe(htmlmin({ collapseWhitespace: true })) // Minify HTML
    .pipe(rename({ extname: '.min.html' })) // Rename files with .min.html extension
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist')); // Destination folder
}

exports.minifyHTML = minifyHTML;
```

and it says to run the above by: `gulp minifyHTML`.

What is wrong with the above codes ad how can I achieve what I am looking for?

Comment: Your code looks fine except use `return gulp.src(['src/**/*.html'])`  - that path is the same as all the other paths you have listed.  Paste the command line errors when it runs.  And the `src` folder should be at the same level as the `gulpfile.js` file.